# preg_replace any style tags expression

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am trying to use preg_replace to remove any thing contained in a style tag. For example:

```
<img src="image.jpg" style="float:left;" />
```

Would be changed to:

```
<img src="image.jpg" />
```

Likewise:

```
<a href="link.html" style="color:#FF0000;" class="someclass">Link</a>
```

Would be changed to:

```
<a href="link.html" class="someclass">Link</a>
```

How would I write this regular expression?

```
preg_replace('EXPRESSION', '', $string);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
preg_replace("@(<[^<>]+)\sstyle\=[\"\'][^\"\']+[\"\']([^<>]+>)@i", '$1$2', $string);
```

Comment: you should add the \s? optional leading space in there right before style, or you leave a double space, :-p, also your second one leaves "Link</a>" because there are no capture groups and you are matching the start < of the tag

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix agreed. Updated.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using the right [**tool**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) for the job and avoid using a regular expression.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;  
$dom->loadHTML($html); 

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);  

foreach ($xpath->query('//*[@style]') as $node) {
    $node->removeAttribute('style'); 
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

[**Working Demo**](https://eval.in/170697)

If you must accomplish this job using a regular expression, the following will suffice.

```
$html = preg_replace('/<[^>]*\Kstyle="[^"]*"\s*/i', '', $html);
```

**Explanation**:

```
<           # '<'
[^>]*       # any character except: '>' (0 or more times)
 \K         #  resets the starting point of the reported match
 style="    #  'style="'
  [^"]*     #    any character except: '"' (0 or more times)
  "         #    '"'
\s*         # whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or more times)
```

[**Working Demo**](https://eval.in/170702)

Comment: +1 for offering **both** a DOM solution and an efficient regex! :)

Answer (score 1):

Look for `style="..."` that is enclosed inside `<` and `>` and replace with matched group `$1$2`

```
(<.*)style="[^"]*"([^>]*>)
```

[Online Demo](http://regex101.com/r/sR4jM8/11)

---

Here is [working sample code](https://eval.in/170687)

Sample code:

```
<?php
    $re = "/(<.*)style=\"[^\"]*\"([^>]*>)/";
    $str = "<img src=\"image.jpg\" style=\"float:left;\" />\n\n<a href=\"link.html\" style=\"color:#FF0000;\" class=\"someclass\">Link</a>";
    $subst = '$1$2';

    $result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
    print $result;
?>
```

Output:

```
<img src="image.jpg"  />

<a href="link.html"  class="someclass">Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the best one I could come up with

```
$re = "/\sstyle\=('|\").*?(?<!\\\\)\1/i";
$str = "<a href=\"link.html\" style=\"color:#FF0000;\"\" class=\"someclass\">Link</a>";
$subst = '';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str, 1);
```

outputs

```
<a href="link.html" class="someclass">Link</a>
```

demo:

http://regex101.com/r/uW2kB8/8

Explanation:

```
   \s match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]
style matches the characters style literally (case insensitive)
\= matches the character = literally
1st Capturing group ('|")
    1st Alternative: '
        ' matches the character ' literally
    2nd Alternative: "
        " matches the character " literally
.*? matches any character (except newline)
    Quantifier: Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed [lazy]
(?<!\\) Negative Lookbehind - Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below
    \\ matches the character \ literally
\1 matches the same text as most recently matched by the 1st capturing group
i modifier: insensitive. Case insensitive match (ignores case of [a-zA-Z])
```

Which will even handle cases like this.

```
<a href="link.html" style="background-image:url(\"..\somimage.png\");" class="someclass">Link</a>
```

and

```
<a href="link.html" style="background-image:url('..\somimage.png');" class="someclass">Link</a>
```

and ( which it wont remove )

```
<a href="link.html" data-style="background-image:url('..\somimage.png');" class="someclass">Link</a>
```

and even

```
<a href='link.html' style='color:#FF0000;' class='someclass'>Link</a>
```

http://regex101.com/r/uW2kB8/11

unlike the other suggestions :)