# Using preg_replace to match html tag style-attributes

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have the following regex:

```
preg_replace('#&lt;(/?(?:pre|p|b|em|u|ul|li|ol|blockquote|h1|h2|h3|h4|h5|strong|br))&gt;#', '<\1>', $this->body);
```

It works fine for replacing tags without style-attributes like:

```
<p>, <b>, <li>
```

However I am trying to make it match tags with style attributes also, like:

```
<p style="margin-left: 20px"> and <p style="text-align: right;">.
```

How can I do that?

Thank you for all your help!

Comment: so you want to remove `<p>...</p>` completely?

Comment: No. I am doing preg_replace on a string (run through htmlspecialentities), to convert some of the tags bag to html.

My regex matches tags without attributes, but I would like it to also match tags with attributes like <p style="margin-left: 20px"> and <p style="text-align: right;">.

Thanks!

Comment: Is `<p align="left">` is a match? or you are looking only for `style` attribute? Is `<p align="left" style="...">`  a match?

Comment: I need only the style attribute - and only for <p>-tags!

Comment: Is `<p align="left" style="...">` a match?

Comment: All other attributes than the style attribute should be omitted!

Comment: @fischer I posted an answer for this previously, see [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24641744/preg-replace-any-style-tags-expression/24642250#24642250](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24641744/preg-replace-any-style-tags-expression/24642250#24642250)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<(/?(?:pre|p|b|em|u|ul|li|ol|blockquote|h1|h2|h3|h4|h5|strong|br))(?: +[a-z]+="[^"]*")*>
```

The last part:

```
(?: +[a-z]+="[^"]*")*
```

matches attributes="xxxxx"

Answer (score 0):

> Form comment : I need only the style attribute - and only for `<p>`-tags!

Get the matched group from index 1.

```
<p.*(style="[^"]*")[^>]*>
```

[Online demo](http://regex101.com/r/lF4hM6/12)

---

> Form comment :All other attributes than the style attribute should be omitted!

Try below sample code to substitute it `p` tag only with style attribute.

sample code:

```
$re = "/<p.*(style=\\"[^\\"]*\\")[^>]*>/m";
$str = "<p style=\"margin-left: 20px\" align=\"left\">\n<p align=\"left\">\n<p align=\"left\" style=\"margin-left: 20px\">\n";
$subst = '<p $1>';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Find detail description on [Grabbing HTML Tags](http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html)